# please, I have an AttributeError bug to fix, Please, help me out

Tags: python, django

I created an address project in my Django project which works fine but I want to the program to avoid users from viewing their billing address and update address page if they have not created an address yet.

This is the views of the code that runs well:

views.py

```
def register_address(request):
    instance = ""
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
           form = AddressForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user 
                instance.save()
                messages.success(request, "You have successfully added a shipping address!")
                return redirect('address:billing_address')
    except:
        pass
    
    return render(request,'address/register_address.html',{'form':form})



def billing_address(request):
    address = "" 
    try:
        address = UserAddress.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except:
        pass

    return render(request,'address/billing_address.html',{'form':address})

def update_address(request):
    form = UpdateForm()
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UpdateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                address = UserAddress.objects.get(user=request.user)
                address.user = request.user
                address.country = request.POST.get("country")
                address.state = request.POST.get("state")
                address.area = request.POST.get("area")
                address.city = request.POST.get("city")
                address.street_name = request.POST.get("street_name")
                address.save()
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully updated address.")
                return redirect('address:billing_address')
    except:
        pass
    
    return render(request,'address/update_address.html',{'form':form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register_address/',views.register_address,name="register_address"),
    path('billing_address/',views.billing_address,name="billing_address"),
    path('update_address/',views.update_address,name="update_address"),
]
```

register_address.html

```
<h2>Register Adress</h2><br>
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="myButton" value="Submit">
</form><br><br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:bi lling_address'%}';">View Billing Address</button>  <button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:update_address' %}';">Update Address</button><br><br>

</div>
```

billing_address.html

```
<br><h1><center>Billing Address page!</center></h1><br>

<div class="container">

<h2>Username:</h2> {{form.user|capfirst}}<br>
<h2>Address:</h2> {{form.street_name|capfirst}}, {{form.area|capfirst}}, {{form.city|capfirst}}, {{form.state|capfirst}}, {{form.country|capfirst}}<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:update_address' %}';">Edit me</button><br><br><br>
```

But here is an extension of the code I want so that users are unable to view their billing address and update address unless they have created address.

views.py

```
    def register_address(request):
        instance = ""
        user = ""
        try:
            form = AddressForm()
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = AddressForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    instance = form.save(commit=False)
                    instance.user = request.user 
                    instance.save()
user=UserAddress.get(user=request.user)
                    messages.success(request, "You have successfully added a shipping address!")
                    return redirect(reverse('address:billing_address',args=[user.pk]))
        except:
            pass
        
        return render(request,'address/register_address.html',{'form':form,'pk':user.pk})
    
    
    
    def billing_address(request,pk):
        user = ""
        try:
            user = UserAddress.objects.get(pk=pk)
            if user is not None:
                return user
        except AttributeError:
            messages.error(request, "Please, create an address before viewing address!")
            return redirect('address:register_address')
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Please, create an address before viewing address!")
            return redirect('address:register_address')
    
        return render(request,'address/billing_address.html',{'form':user})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register_address/',views.register_address,name="register_address"),
    path('<int:pk>billing_address/',views.billing_address,name="billing_address"),
    path('update_address/',views.update_address,name="update_address"),
]
```

register_addres.html

```
    <h2>Register Adress</h2><br>
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="myButton" value="Submit">
</form><br><br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:billing_address' pk=pk %}';">View Billing Address</button>  <button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:update_address' %}';">Update Address</button><br><br>
```

billing_address.html

```
<div class="container">

<h2>Username:</h2> {{form.user|capfirst}}<br>
<h2>Address:</h2> {{form.street_name|capfirst}}, {{form.area|capfirst}}, {{form.city|capfirst}}, {{form.state|capfirst}}, {{form.country|capfirst}}<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:update_address' %}';">Edit me</button><br><br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the error correctly? I mean full traceback. From where the error is coming from, see how to make [repro].

Comment: @SunderamDubey Ive pasted the traceback error, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many minor mistakes such as:

1. The route should be `billing_address/<int:pk>/` not `<int:pk>billing_address/`.
2. In `register_address` view, `pk` is an empty string in case of `GET` request, so how can you send an empty string to `billing_address` view, if it is current logged in user (Assuming already have relationship with inbuilt User model of Django via ForeignKey, AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser or anything) so you can just send `request.user.id` to the `billing_address` view.

Try to use below code.

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register_address/',views.register_address,name="register_address"),
    path('billing_address/<int:pk>/',views.billing_address,name="billing_address"),
    path('update_address/',views.update_address,name="update_address"),
]
```

register_address.html

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="myButton" value="Submit">
</form><br><br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick = "window.location= '{% url 'address:billing_address' pk=request.user.id %}';">View Billing Address</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @SunderamDubey , I am no longer seeing AttributeError but after a user has created an address , a user is still unable to view address despite an already existing address in the database. I will update the code to what I have currently. Thanks for the help, I really found your code helpful.

Comment: I have updated the code to what I have at the moment. Please, kIndly check it out.

Comment: @IbikunleTheCreator Are you talking about `register_address` it seems the issue of making wrong relationships, can you share `AddressForm()` and the model associating with it, assuming you have done no changes in the `register_address.html` template.

Comment: I have uploaded my model.py and forms.py.

Comment: Oh, I noticed it. I totally forgot. it was helpful .. thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 0):

A view should always return [**`HttpResponse(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) or one of its subclasses but you are returning string from the view i.e. `return reverse('address:billing_address',args=[user.pk])` will return string. So return response object instead of string in your view as

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('address:billing_address', args=[user.pk]))
```

Change accordingly in other `return reverse` also.

Comment: Thank you very much @user8193706, I have fixed the mistake in the code, But a user is still unable to view address despite having an address saved in the data base already.